# Solspace Calendar - Use checkboxes to dynamicly filter displayed events

Tags: categories, solspace-calendar

I would like to have a row of checkboxes representing event categories so I can select which categories are displayed on the active calendar.

Would be best if checking or unchecking automatically refreshed the calendar (or entire page if needed) without a submit button.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Thanks!

Greg

Comment: Are you familiar with javascript and ajax? Because that would be one way to do this: submit a form through ajax (i.e. without clicking a submit button), in which you would be sending the checked categories data (eg. an array or category_ids) in the background to a template that will parse this data to return with a new filtered Calendar view. It's a fairly advanced subject, so I suggest you make sure you know the basics of javascript/jQuery/Ajax beforehand.

Comment: If are _are_ familiar with javscript/ajax, the following will make more sense: it's a page with an ajax script that you can use in many situations, including this one: http://support.solspace.com/solution/articles/119581 (you need to tweak to your needs, of course)